# How to search List<> with Json Generic deserialized object

Tags: linq, json, .net-3.5

I need to filter a generic List with data from a Json object.  I have the deserialized object in a list with `{name:'', value:''}`.  I need to search a data contract (which is also a list) with name as the field to search, and value as the value of the field.  How do I accomplish these as they are generic. 
Here is the method:

```
public List<StaffingPositionsDataContract> GetStaffingPosition(string searchFilters)
{
    List<serializedForm> deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<serializedForm>>(searchFilters);
    List<StaffingPositionsDataContract> staffingPositionResponse = new StaffingPositionsDataContract().LoadMockData();

    deserializedObject.ForEach(delegate(serializedForm filter) {


       });

    return staffingPositionResponse;
}
```

I wanted to try something simple as this:

```
var query = staffingPositionResponse .Where(filter.name + ".Contains(@0)", filter.value);
```

But Where does not except 2 arguments.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use something like

```
List<SerializedForm >.FindAll( delegate(SerializedForm filter)
{
   return filter.name.IndexOf(filter.value) != -1;
});
```

Comment: oops that should be deserializedObject.FindAll

Comment: That looks good, but how do I tie that to my other list. Or how do I filter my data contract list with those values?

Comment: The FindAll method is a filter method, it returns a new list with a subset of the items in the first list.

So if you are wanting to filter your staffingPositionResponse you would call 

List<StaffingPositionsDataContract> filteredList =  staffingPositionResponse.FindAll(delegate(StaffingPositionsDataContract position)
{
    return DoesContractMeetFilter(deserializedObject, position);
});

Comment: private bool DoesContractMeetFilter(List<serializedForm> filters, StaffingPositionsDataContract position)
{
 
   return filters.FindAll(delegate(serializedForm filter)
{
 return position.name.IndexOf(filter.value) != -1;
}).Count > 0;
}

Comment: Yes I see what you are doing, however position does not contain a definition for name, filter does.  So if I switch position.name to filter.name, it doesn't filter anything.  The problem is StaffingPositionsDataContract has 7 DataMembers to filter on, but the json object doesn't match.  Thats why this is so difficult, but with the anwser, would be a really nice piece of code.

Comment: ok so instead of just filtering on the name use a chained conditional statement like


return position.Field1.IndexOf(filter.Value) != -1
       || position.Field2.IndexOf(filter.Value) != -1
       || position.Field3.IndexOf(filter.Value) != -1
       || position.Field4.IndexOf(filter.Value) != -1
       || position.Field5.IndexOf(filter.Value) != -1
       || position.Field6.IndexOf(filter.Value) != -1
       || position.Field7.IndexOf(filter.Value) != -1;

Instead of return position.name.IndexOf(filter.value) != -1;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a million Peter! Here is what I ended up with to suit my needs:

```
   private bool DoesContractMeetFilter(List<SerializedForm> filters, StaffingPositionsDataContract position)
    {   
        return filters.FindAll(delegate(SerializedForm filter)
        {
            return string.Equals(position.PositionId.ToString(), filter.value) && 
                string.Equals(position.Series, filter.value) &&
                string.Equals(position.OrgLocation,filter.value) &&
                string.Equals(position.DutyStation, filter.value) &&
                string.Equals(position.BudgetStatus, filter.value)&&
                string.Equals(position.BudgetingEntity, filter.value) &&
                string.Equals(position.BFY, filter.value);
        }).Where(x => x.value != "" || x.value != null || x.value.ToUpper() != "ALL").Count() > 0;
    }
```

This works great, but I would be EXTREMELY impressed if I could globalize this so all my other data contracts could consume it!

Comment: IF all your other contracts use a common base class or an interface then simply move the method to a static class and then pass in the base class or interface as a parameter instead of the staffing position data contract.

Comment: The classes do not share a base class, or an interface.  I can change them to be that way, but since all the properties of each class are totally different, I'm not sure how to use this without a switch statement.